# Cannot access attributes of default Chef recipe in child recipe attributes file

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, cubrid

I have several recipes in my [cubrid](https://github.com/kadishmal/cubrid-chef) cookbook which I use to install [CUBRID Database](http://www.cubrid.org) on a Vagrant box. Each recipe has its own attributes file. Eg:

```
# attributes/default.rb for recipe/default.rb
default['cubrid']['home'] = "/opt/cubrid"
```

Then:

```
# attributes/demodb.rb for recipe/demodb.rb
set['cubrid']['demodb_dir'] = "#{node['cubrid']['home']}/databases/demodb"
```

Then in my *recipe/demodb.rb* I refer to its attributes like:

```
include_recipe "cubrid"

CUBRID_DEMODB_DIR = "#{node['cubrid']['demodb_dir']}"

# create a "demodb" directory if it doesn't exist
directory "#{CUBRID_DEMODB_DIR}" do
  user "vagrant"
  action :create
  not_if "test -d #{CUBRID_DEMODB_DIR}"
end
```

The above should create **/opt/cubrid/databases/demodb** directory. But it fails, because it tries to create **/databases/demodb** directory, meaning **#{node['cubrid']['home']}** was not set.

**How do I correctly reference the attributes set in the parent attributes file?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [Chef Wiki](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Attributes+Cookbook) => **Cookbook Attribute File Ordering**

Use

```
include_attribute 'cubrid'
```

in your attributes/demodb.rb